# 4 Digit Pin Regex

Tags: regex, validation

Using a jQuery [Bootstrapvalidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) and am trying to add additional validation for a 4 digit pin for a financial app.

So I have gotten as far as making sure the user's input has 4 digits and is numeric.

```
/^\d{4}$/
```

Now I am trying to do the following additional regex validations and am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Make sure 4 digits aren't all the same (ie. 1111 or 9999)
2. Not sequential (ie. 1234, 6789)
3. Not a birth year. To simplify, I am just excluding any number that starts with 19 or 20 (ie. 1986, 2004).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to do all these validations using regex?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't specify that I am using BootstrapValidator.

Comment: For those of us who don't know what BootstrapValidator is, does that imply that you *have* to use a regexp (and only a regexp) for this? A brute force solution would be to generate a list of all 9000+ valid PINs, then join them with `|`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first and third constraints are easy to translate to regex:

```
^(?!(.)\1{3})(?!19|20)\d{4}$
```

Here, I used two negative lookaheads, one for each constraint.

However, the non-sequential constraint, while possible, would be unreasonably convoluted for a regex to handle.

Here, you decide if it's worth the pain:

```
^(?!(.)\1{3})(?!19|20)(?!0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|0987|9876|8765|7654|6543|5432|4321|3210)\d{4}$
```

Comment: how regex would check for sequential?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. Just tried all 3 solutions and they work.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Just to note there is a redundant '9876' in the sequential example above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an appropriate use of regular expressions.  You will probably want to validate this using code since there might be a list of specific numbers you want to ban, in addition to other rules that are difficult to enforce via regular expressions.  Even if you are able to do this using regex, the resulting expression will be unreadable and unmaintainable.